# How to understand the basis of LP problems given by HiGHS solver?

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, linear-programming, api

Here is part of a ".bas" file given by HiGHS using serial dual simplex method to solve an LP problem:

HiGHS v1
Valid
# Columns 57471
3 1 1 3 3 1 1 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 3 1 ...

What does the number "3" mean? I know that "1" indicates the basic variables, "0" indicates the non-basic variables at their lower bounds and "2" indicates the non-basic variables at their upper bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the enum documentation:

https://ergo-code.github.io/HiGHS/stable/structures/enums/#HighsBasisStatus

But you have to infer that `kLower` is `0` and so on.

The status 3 is `kZero`: A free variable is nonbasic and set to zero